# Check if Java InputStream comes from Socket

Tags: java, sockets, abstract-class

I have a class that takes an InputStream as an argument to read data.

```
public Foo {
  private DataInput in;

  public Foo(InputStream ism) {
    in = new DataInputStream(ism);
  }

  public byte readByte() throws IOException {
    return in.readByte();
  }
}
```

Sometimes this InputStream might come from a Socket, e.g.,

```
ism = new BufferedInputStream(sock.getInputStream());
foo = new Foo(ism);
```

My question is, is it possible to check from within Foo that the input stream comes from Socket, i.e., it's a network I/O rather than local I/O? Since the

```
socket.getInputStream
```

call returns the abstract class. I don't know which concrete input stream implementation to test for.

Edit: the motivation is that there is a piece of big Java software that has this structure. `Foo` is created in many places. Some place with file input stream while others with socket input stream. The software can perform poorly when the read is across the network. So I want to see if it's possible do tracing to differentiate the two scenarios for this software without changing much of its code. I'm using AspectJ to write the tracing in the hope to not create much mess to this existing software.

Comment: No (at least not without an ugly reflection-based solution), since you're wrapping it into a BufferedInputStream. But you shouldn't have to care: an InputStream is an InputStream is an InputStream. What are you trying to achieve?

Comment: No, you've written the entire interface of `Foo` to be independent of and isolated from sockets. If you want `Foo` to know about sockets, you'd have to give it a socket.

Comment: I need to do some tracing to differentiate when Foo is doing network read instead of local File read.

Comment: try **System.out.println(in.getClass().getName())** , and it will surely indicate if your InputStream is coming from a file or socket. For InputStream coming from Sockets, **in.getClass().getName()** will surely return a different result

Comment: If you can only modify `Foo`, then there is no pretty solution. Can you modify the classes that use `Foo`, or are they too numerous?

Comment: This is part of a big software. Foo is used in many places. Some place passed with a regular inputstream, while others passed with a socket input stream. I'm using AspectJ to do the tracing so the hope is to create fewer mess to the software's code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that an InputStream can be a FilterInputStream that is constructed around another InputStream and that socket just returns an InputStream.

One approach, very *dirt & buggy*: find the root InputStream, that is, recursively/loop if it is an instance of FilterInputStream, check its parent InputStream (protected field `in`). Then check the class of the root, the name probably contains "Socket" if it comes from a Socket.

AspectJ idea (I do not have that much experience with it): you should be able to add an aspect to the `getInputStream` method of Socket that stores the returned InputStream in a list (or similar) for later checking, or somehow marks that InputStream (adding a flag/method to it?).

Answer (score 0):

You can create 2 superclasses of input stream before passing it into `Foo` class.

```
NetworkInputStream nis = new NetworkInputStream(sock.getInputStream());
Foo networkFoo = new Foo(nis);

FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(file.getInputStream());
Foo fileFoo = new Foo(fis);


public class NetworkInputStream extends BufferedInputStream {}

public class FileInputStream extends BufferedInputStream {}
```

Then, on Foo class:

```
public Foo(InputStream ism) {
    if (ism instanceof NetworkInputStream) {
        //Do whatever if it's from network stream 
    }
    if (ism instanceof FileInputStream) {
       //Do whateverelse
    }
    in = new DataInputStream(ism);
}
```